# Unable to delete file using AJAX/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If I try to delete a file without using AJAX and only php, it works fine but using AJAX code does nothing. Here's the code with AJAX.
index.php =>

```
<form method="post" action="include/delete.php" id="del-form">
       <input type="text" name="file-name" class="file-name-manager" required />
       <button class='btn-nav-class1'><i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>
     </form>
```

delete.php=>

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
$sessionid = $_SESSION['u_id'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['file-name']);
    $file = "../files/".$sessionid.'/'.$name;
    if(!unlink($file)){
      echo "File not deleted";
    } else {
      echo "File deleted";
    }
    header("Location: ../index.php?delete=success");
```

and with AJAX I used the code=>

```
$("#del-form").bind('submit',function(e){
          $.ajax({url: "include/delete.php", success: function(result){
              alert("done");
          }
        });
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
```

What I want is it to delete the file without redirecting to delete.php and have to redirect back to index.php. But after using the code, it just shows the alert message and doesn't delete the file.

Comment: You don't pass the `file-name`

Comment: Pass the file-name where?

Comment: See my answer Below

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not meant for escaping filenames. You need to properly escape the filename, removing any extra `../` and such

Comment: comment the redirect..enable error reporting and check if the unlink throws an error

Comment: The file path isn't the issue and maybe its not a good practice but its functional right now. I'll change it but as for the AJAX problem, its still pertaining as you can see from the screenshot I commented down below on Akintunde's answer. I made these changes https://prnt.sc/hc0vax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ajax function to this -

```
                var fileName = $("[name='file-name']").val();

                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'include/delete.php',
                    data: {
                     'file-name': fileName
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                    //alert(response); 
                    console.log(response);
                    }
                });
```

and in delete.php , delete last header location line.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed (: